# How to reopen a closed click event in jQuery without reload?

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I am trying to reopen a closed `click event` using `jQuery` but I don't want to refresh my page for it. For better understanding,please take a look at what I really want:

```
$(function (){
Var i = 0;
Var j =0;
$("#first").on("click" , function (){
i++;
});
$("#second").on("click" , function (){
j++;
});
if(i = j){
$("first").off("click");
}
$("#third").on("click" , function (){
alert("what should I write here to reopen #first ID closed click event, without any refresh or reload");
});
});
```

> After I click my #third ID, I want my #first ID with closed click event to start responding again on click!

### Edited |

*Why I want to do this: I've to use `off()` ,  so that no one can add anything in the list given in my website,  by clicking `#first` ID once the limit is exceeded, and can only be able to do so after removing previous list which is already full ...*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow the use case, but couldn't you just put an if statement inside the first click and only increment if `i` does not equal `j`, or only if `i` is less than `j`?

If that works, you can remove the .off()

Comment: I simply can not do what you are saying, because I've to use `off()` ,  so that no one can add anything in the list given in my site,  by clicking `#first` ID once the limit exceeded, and can only be able to do so after removing previous list which is already full .... It is more complicated than what you are guessing ...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Based on the example, it seemed like you could just disable the code inside click that way. Would detach() be a better solution, or maybe this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23070551/3103434

Comment: Dear `Spudly` I think detach() method keeps data and events, how a closed event can be reintroduced using this method? Can you explain!?

Comment: I didn't see a way to bind .on() again once .off() has been called, so to be honest, I'm not really sure. I haven't run into a use case like this before. 

It looked like you might be able to call attach() after detach(), so I was guessing that might be worth looking into. If not, hopefully someone else will post here that has better experience with this type of use case.